# What is {{if condition}} {{/if}} in jsp

Tags: jsp

I have just got few jsp files to go through and prepare a document. In these jsp's i see the developer has used if condition in {{}} these bracket. Can anyone tell me if these are JSP tags or some tag library may have been included.

PS: I am pretty new to JSP.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

That's not jsp, so it's likely some kind of javascript library. For instance, AngularJS uses the `{{}}` to include logic in html.

In jsp, the if-condition is done with the tag `<c:if test="some condition">...</c:if>`

Comment: Thank you for answering popovitsj. I just noticed that these are jquery template and if condition is in jquery template. Anyways thanks a lot for answering. :)